# Static member functions in namesapce

Tags: c++, namespaces, static-functions

I have static member function inside my class which I would like to add in my namespace.

```
class A{
public:
    static void func();
};

namespace myNamespace{
    void A::func(){
    ...
    }
}

int main(){
   myNamespace::A::func;
}
```

I get the following errors:

- error: definition of ‘void A::func()’ is not in namespace enclosing ‘A’  [-fpermissive]
- error: ‘myNamespace::A’ has not been declared
  myNamespace::A::func();
   void A::func(){

what is the reason?

Comment: Which part of the error didn't you understand?

Comment: Why is `class A` defined outside of `namespace myNamespace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you put a function that belongs to the class A inside namespace. just make the class and function A together inside namespace your code should be like this

```
namespace myNamespace {
class A {
public:
    static void func();
};


    void A::func() {

    }
}
int main()
{

    myNamespace::A::func;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration and the definition both should be inside the NameSpace for it to work. Here in your code, you have declared the class outside the namespace. You can fix it as follows.

```
namespace myNamespace{

    class A{
    public:
        static void func();
    };


    void A::func(){
    ...
    }
}

int main(){
   myNamespace::A::func;
}
```

Also try to understand the error messages which would save you a lot of time googling.

https://www.crashhandler.com/ ---> Best Practices in C++ {EDIT :: A blog by myself}

Comment: Are you affiliated with that linked site? If so, you better make it clear in the answer. Honest disclosure is important on SO.

Comment: Yes it's my blog. I will edit it. Thanks for noting it :)